# NETEM: how to define a Gaussian distribution without specifying standard deviation?

Tags: linux, networking, delay, iproute

I am using Netem to generate a Gaussian distribution profile for one-way delay.

I have read that the command `sudo tc qdisc change dev eth2 root netem delay 100ms 20ms distribution normal` will make the distribution of delay normal between the range of 100ms ± 20ms.

While it's clear that this Gaussian should be centered in 100ms, what about the standard deviation? According to the documentation, the ±20ms represents a *correlation*, not the standard deviation.
Does anybody know how the latter is defined?